# Bayes Formula with Joint Probability: Is this Correct?

Tags: probability, bayesian

I'm having trouble with the Bayes formula when I have a conditional probability, as part of the result of the equation.

If this is the initial equation:

$$\text{Pr}(A|B)=\frac{\text{Pr}(B|A)\text{Pr}(A)}{\text{Pr}(B|A)\text{Pr}(A)+\text{Pr}(B|A^C)\text{Pr}(A^C)}$$

And the question I want to answer is:

$$\text{Pr}(X_2\ | \ (X_1 and \ Y))$$

Where i in $$\text(X_i)$$ can be between 1 and 10.

Am I correct in stating, the Bayes formula is:

$$\text{Pr}(X_2 \ | \ (X_1 and \ Y)=\frac{\text{Pr}(X_1 and \ Y\ |\ X_2)\text{Pr}(X)}{\text{Pr}(X_1 and \ Y|X_1)\text{Pr}(X_1)+\text{Pr}(X_1 and \ Y|X_1)\text{Pr}(X_2)}$$

I feel like I'm on the right track, but it is the use of the joint distribution, between X1 and Y that is throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

The formula $P(A|B)P(B)$ can be read as the probability of A given B (B is the conditioning event) multiplied by the probability of event B.
So what is wrong in your formula is that you are not multiplying the conditioned event by the probability of the conditioning event, on the numerator where you write $P(X_1 and Y |X_2)P(X)$ it should be $P(X_1 and Y |X_2)P(X_2)$ and so follows for the denominator.

Comment: Would this formula change if X2 is conditional on X1 occurring?

Comment: Also the sum of probabilities for X1 and X2, don't sum to 1 ... is it still right to have P(X) in the numerator, if we're not accounting for them in the denominator?

Comment: Then you should define what $Y$ is and in which $X_i$ you are working